# pykafka topics return None

Tags: python, apache-kafka, pykafka

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient

client = KafkaClient(hosts='192.168.199.87:9092') 

topics = client.topics
print(topics)
```

the result of topics is a dict  with all values are None:

```
{b'user_name_topic': None, b'test_topic': None}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: And what's the issue? You're asking Kafka to give you the list of topics but you get a dict whose keys are the topic. Is this what troubles you?

Comment: @FrankBr yes, it is same as [issue] (https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/670)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix it in py3:

```
topic = client.topics[b'test']
```

client.topics don't return a available dict bescause the weak references

Answer (score 0):

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/670) for an overview of why this happens. It's not a bug, just a strange byproduct of PyKafka's use of weak references to `Topic` instances.